# How to run commands in your website without using a SSH connection

Tags: php, laravel, hosting, web-hosting

Anyone using Single web hosting plan by Hostinger?
If yes then how you're running commands because surprisingly they don't offer SSH in this plan.

I'm trying to run a Laravel website there and without a command prompt I can't run commands like `php artisan key:generate` or `composer install`.

You might think of running commands using Artisan but I can't do that either because I can't even access the website without generating a key.

Comment: Do everything locally, then upload the files.

Comment: What does the hoster suggest you use? After all, there must be _some_ kind of upload facility available to you.

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question and it is off-topic on Stack Overflow. Non-programming questions about your website should be asked on [webmasters.se]. Please delete your question here and re-ask it there.

Comment: @Olivier Thanks...This is what I did in the end.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt What they suggests is really funny. They told me to setup a cron job and and then run my command from there.

Answer (score -1):

I understand that with your plan you only need to use `ftp` or do an upgrade. They have a very strange policy, they give access to git but without ssh ))  At the moment I see that the price for Premium is the same as for Single, we can think about it.

If you decide to upgrade:

##### Upgrade Version

Log in to `hpanel`, in the sidebar select `Advanced -> SSH Access`. On this page you should see the ssh login details. (host, port, user). You can log in with public ssh, either by preloading it or by password.

```
ssh -p PORT USER@HOST
```

But installing laravel on hosting has its own subtleties, you may find this article useful https://support.hostinger.com/en/articles/6152127-how-to-deploy-laravel-8-at-hostinger.

Then install the [composer2](https://getcomposer.org/download/) in your home directory `cd ~`

```
php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"
php -r "if (hash_file('sha384', 'composer-setup. php') === 'e21205b207c3ff031906575712edab6f13eb0b361f2085f1f1237b7126d785e826a450292b6cfd1d64d92e6563bbde02') { echo 'Installer verified'; } else { echo 'Installer corrupted'; unlink('composer-setup.php'); } echo PHP_EOL;"
php composer-setup.php
php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');"
```

Answer (score -3):

Open SSH from the browser
Step 1: Install OpenSSH. Make sure you have OpenSSH installed on Windows 10. ...
Step 2: Download the wrapper script. An ssh link follows this syntax, ssh://@: but open ssh expects a different format. ...
Step 3: Register the script as URL handler. ...
Step4: Activate the new handler.

Comment: I don't think this answers the question at all. Without server-side SSH, what's the point of configuring it locally in any way?